redux-devtools-extension not uninstalling
I am trying to uninstall redux-devtools-extension from dependencies of the project, but instead it is installing again.
 
Also tried npm uninstall redux-devtools/extension
I am expecting that the package gets uninstall.
npm version: 10.8.3
redux-devtools/extension: 3.3.0


The dependency is "@redux-devtools/extension", not "redux-devtools/extension", the "@" is part of the package name. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

You could also just delete it from your package.json file and delete the entire node_modules directory and re-run npm install to get rid of it.

Try uninstalling by running this command:
npm uninstall @redux-devtools-extension

Check it in package.lock.json, whether it is there or not:
If it is not there, delete node_modules folder and package.json file. Then run the following command:
npm install 

then this package won't appear again.
